# VB check if textbox contains text in a specific alphanumeric format

Tags: vb.net, validation, textbox

is it possible to check if textbox value contains alphanumeric in a specific format:

begins with two capital alpha characters followed by six numeric

eg: SO123456

I'd prefer the check in code behind

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a bit of regex

```
    Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("([A-Z]{2})([0-9]{6})")

Dim match As Match = regex.Match(TextBox1.Text)

If (match.Success) Then
MessageBox.Show("Valid")
Else
MessageBox.Show("Not Valid")
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this also:

```
Dim str As String = TextBox1.Text.Trim()
    Dim num As Integer            
    If str.Length = 8 _
    And Convert.ToInt32(str(0)) > 64 _
    And Convert.ToInt32(str(0)) < 91 _
    And Convert.ToInt32(str(1)) > 64 _
    And Convert.ToInt32(str(1)) < 91 _
    And Integer.TryParse(str.Substring(2, 6), num) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Correct id.")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Wrong id.")
    End If
```

Hope it helps.